# SQL Help | The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list

Tags: mysql

Please see my query below,

```
insert into dbo.orderDetails(orderNo,clientId,productId,quantity)
values(' ee941422-5546-4d62-b5d6-60ecd13ca2b8 ')
select client_id,product_id,amount from dbo.cart
where client_id =' efc08f7c-fdfc-4712-9488-fc1c55acb95e ' ;
```

In this I want a static orderno and the rest should come from the a table(dbo.cart).when i execute my query its shows this error

```
There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the 
VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the 
number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
```

Any solution.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? `dbo` is usually SQL-Server.

Comment: The number of columns in your `VALUES()` needs to match the number of columns in your table you are inserting into.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both `VALUES` and `SELECT`. If you want to insert static values, put it into the `SELECT` list.

```
insert into dbo.orderDetails(orderNo,clientId,productId,quantity)
select ' ee941422-5546-4d62-b5d6-60ecd13ca2b8 ', client_id,product_id,amount from dbo.cart
where client_id =' efc08f7c-fdfc-4712-9488-fc1c55acb95e ' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been resolved,  Below is the query which is working for me

INSERT INTO Exam_Trigger(Questions,CAT_ID,TOPIC_ID,SCHEDULED_TYPE,UPDATE_USER,UPDATE_DT,CREATE_USER,CREATE_DT)
select id ,'2','2','Weekly','',curdate(),'',curdate() from ( select  GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',')as id from(select id from question_data order by rand() limit 4)as ls) as ps